# Remove the string value after @ for specific field in aura iteration

Tags: lightning, aura

I have a situation where i want to display the field value which should show sub string value of field inside aura iteration eg email field is test1.user1@gmail.com i want to display value as test1.user1. ho can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should perform the substring extraction in the JS controller (substr function) or within the apex method and use it in the HTML markup (instead of trying to get it done in the HTML)